# Proof By Induction and Generating a formula

Tags: proof-writing, induction

```
x = n
while x > 0:
   x = x // 2
```

Let $x_k$ denote the variable `x` after $k$ iterations.

How do I prove by induction that $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \frac{n}{2^k} - \frac{2^k - 1}{2^k} \leq x_k \leq \frac{n}{2^k} $?

Given: $\forall x\in \mathbb{Z}, \frac{x -1}{2} \leq \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor \leq \frac{x}{2}$.

I started off by thinking what $x_k$ should be. I think it is something like $\lfloor n / 2\rfloor^k$ but I have a feeling this is wrong? Could anyone guide me in the right direction and provide a clue to the induction?

Comment: "We are allowed to use the fact that"  Who's going to stop you?  Is the fact actually true?  If I said "Gee, I don't know, could you explain why that is true" could you?  If so, then of course you can use it.  If it's true and you can prove it is true you can use anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x_k$ is what you get when you write $n$ in base $2$ and erase the last $k$ bits (=binary digits). Specifically, the map $f : x \mapsto \lfloor x/2 \rfloor$ erases one bit from $x$. For example, if $n = 110110101011_2$ then $x_4 = 11011010_2$.

If the last $k$ bits are $0$ then $x_k$ is exactly $n/2^k$. If the last $k$ bits are $1$, then because $11\dots11_2 = 1 + 2 + \dots + 2^{k-1} = 2^k  - 1$,
$$ x_k = \frac{n - (2^k - 1)}{2^k} $$
since subtracting $2^k - 1$ zeroes the last $k$ bits. In general, it follows that $x_k$ must be between these two extremes.

Now, if you want to prove this inductively, you need an inductive definition. That being $x_k = f(x_{k-1})$. So $x_0 = n$ and $x_1 = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ and $x_2 = \lfloor \lfloor n/2 \rfloor /2 \rfloor$ and $x_3 = \lfloor \lfloor \lfloor n/2 \rfloor /2 \rfloor/2 \rfloor$ and so forth.

So now you assume that $$\frac n{2^k} - \frac{2^k - 1}{2^k} \le x_k \le \frac n{2^k} \tag{1}$$ (the inductive hypothesis). Then use the inequality you mentioned with $f(x)$ to obtain

$$ \frac{x_k -1}{2} \leq x_{k+1}= \left\lfloor \frac{x_k}{2} \right\rfloor \leq \frac{x_k}{2}. \tag{2}$$

Combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ and you have what you want.

Comment: I've linked a question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591988/algorithm-and-generating-expressions-that-satisfy-a-condition. It is closely related to this problem.

Comment: I noticed that $x_k$ is not an integer for some $n$. So should we floor $x_k$?

Comment: $x_k$ is always an integer because it's by definition the floor of $x_{k-1}/2$. @Zexion12

Comment: OK! I understand!

Comment: How do I prove the left bound: $\frac{n}{2^{k + 1}} - \frac{2^{k+1} - 1}{2^{k+1}} \leq x_{k+1}$

Comment: If $L(k) = \frac{n}{2^k} - \frac{2^k - 1}{2^k}$ then show that when you substitute $L(k)$ into $(2)$ you get $\frac{L(k) - 1}{2} = L(k + 1)$.

Comment: So we know $L(k) \leq x_k$ so is it true that $\lfloor \frac{L(k)}{2} \rfloor \leq \lfloor \frac{x_k}{2} \rfloor$? Then if it is, is this correct? $L(k+1) = \frac{L(k) - 1}{2} \leq \lfloor \frac{L(k)}{2} \rfloor \leq \lfloor \frac{x_k}{2} \rfloor = x_{k+1}$

Comment: Yes, that's right @Zexion12

Comment: Could you please help with this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591988/algorithm-and-generating-expressions-that-satisfy-a-condition ?